# Adding up values at different levels in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I have a table of hashed values. Here is what it looks like

```
hash_of_errors =
    {
      'i0': 
         {
            200: 
                 {
                   0: 12,
                   1: 23
                 },
            300: 
                 {
                   0: 4,
                   1: 3
                 }
            },
        'i1': 
         {
            100: 
                 {
                   0: 2,
                   1: 23
                 },
            300: 
                 {
                   0: 4,
                   1: 3
                 }
            }
    }
```

So it's a hash with

- first level: unit names i0, i1, i2 etc
- second level: counts: 200, 300, 400 etc.
- third level: level: 0, 1  etc.
- and values are number of errors.

What I want to do is create a 2d array with first index is per unit, and second index is total number of errors per counts (sum of all errors at level 0,1). In this case I will get this.

```
[[0, 35, 7], #i0 unit: 37 (12+23) for count 200, 7 for 300 and 0s for 100
 [24, 0, 7]] #i1 unit: 24 for count 100, 7 for 300 and 0s for 200
```

Second 2d array/list I need to print has first index is per level (across all the i0, i1) and second index is total numbers of errors per counts

```
[[2, 12, 8] #0 level: at count 100 we have 2, at 300 we have 8(4+4)
 [23, 23, 7]] #1 level: at count of 100 we have 23, at 300 we have 7(4+3)
```

How do I do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could basically do all of them with some comprehensions. The first one would be:

```
>>> units = ['i0', 'i1']
>>> counts = [100, 200, 300]
>>> levels = [0, 1]

>>> [[sum(hash_of_errors[unit].get(count, {}).values()) for count in counts] for unit in units]
[[0, 35, 7], [25, 0, 7]]
```

The second one is a bit more complicated because you need to iterate over all of them:

```
>>> [[sum(hash_of_errors[unit].get(count, {}).get(level, 0) for unit in units) for count in counts] for level in levels]
[[2, 12, 8], [23, 23, 6]]
```

---

Note that you could also use manual iterations instead of comprehensions. They won't be one-liners but maybe better to understand.

For example:

```
# To translate name to position
units = {'i0': 0, 'i1': 1}
counts = {100: 0, 200: 1, 300: 2}
levels = {0: 0, 1: 1}

res = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]  # basic result, we will modify these values as we go along
for unit, unitdict in hash_of_errors.items():
    for count, countdict in unitdict.items():
        for level, errorcount in countdict.items():
            res[units[unit]][counts[count]] += errorcount
>>> res
[[0, 35, 7], [25, 0, 7]]
```

or in the second case:

```
res = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
for unit, unitdict in hash_of_errors.items():
    for count, countdict in unitdict.items():
        for level, errorcount in countdict.items():
            res[levels[level]][counts[count]] += errorcount
>>> res
[[2, 12, 8], [23, 23, 6]]
```

Comment: That works....thanks for detailed explanation. I like your suggestion of using defaultdict and playing with it.

Comment: @Romeo No problem. I have removed the `defaultdict` in the latest edit because it works just as well with a zeros `res` list. :)